# Convert code to Linux kernel style

Tags: command-line

I used to know a command to convert code to Linux kernel style with proper brackets and spacing and whatnot.

It used indent, but I don't remember the rest. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

A scripts/cvt_kernel_style.pl: kernel style source code **[reformatter](http://lwn.net/Articles/380161/)**.

A script to convert kernel source files to a more conformant style.
A supplement to or replacement of Lindent.
A wretched little perl script using regexes.

It's a stupid little tool, don't expect it to be perfect.  It's not.

Conversions should be done one at a time.
Multiple conversions may be performed together, but it's not recommended.

Not all conversions are performed correctly.
Verify all conversions before committing anything.

If the original source file doesn't compile, then any conversion will not
compile either and may eat your source.

Do not use option `--overwrite` unless you have another copy of the source file.

No option exists to wrap long lines.

Command line use:

```
$ ./scripts/cvt_kernel_style.pl --help
usage: ./scripts/cvt_kernel_style.pl [options] <files>
version: 0.1
```

But better is to know what is the coding style:

Linux Kernel Coding Style (by Linus Torvalds)

---

This is a short document describing the preferred coding style for the linux kernel.
Coding style is very personal, and I won't
force
my views on anybody, but this is what
goes for anything that I have to be able to maintain, and I'd prefer it for most other things
too. Please at least consider the points made **[here](http://slurm.schedmd.com/coding_style.pdf)**:

Chapter 1: Indentation

Chapter 2: Placing Braces

Chapter 3: Naming

Chapter 4: Functions

Chapter 5: Commenting

Chapter 6: You've made a mess of it

Comment: I found that script but it wouldn't work. Whatever `indent` command I used worked great though.

I will have to try and force myself to use Kernel style naturally. After a while of using Allman, and then K&R, this is a big change.